# Jquery adding value at the back of the number

Tags: jquery

So i got a problem with my code, i'm trying to add 1000 but instead of the value being 1027.50, its 27.501000. What can the problem be?

It works with subtracting numbers and multiplying, but not with adding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#a1').keyup(calculate);
            $('#a2').keyup(calculate);
            $('#a3').keyup(calculate);
            $(".checkbox_check").change(calculate);
            $(".checkbox_check2").change(calculate);
            $(".checkbox_check3").change(calculate);
        });
        function calculate(e) {

        if ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked') && ($('input.checkbox_check2').is(':checked'))) {
            $('#a4').val(($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val())* 1.1).val(parseFloat($('#a4').val()).toFixed(2));
            $('#a3').val($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val());
            if ($('input.checkbox_check3').is(':checked')) {
                $('#a4').val($('#a4').val() + 1000);             <---- HERE
            }
        } else if ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked')) {
            $('#a4').val(($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val())* 0.7).val(parseFloat($('#a4').val()).toFixed(2));
            $('#a3').val($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val());
        } else if ($('input.checkbox_check2').is(':checked')) {
            $('#a4').val(($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val())* 0.9).val(parseFloat($('#a4').val()).toFixed(2));
            $('#a3').val($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val());  
        } else {
            $('#a4').val(($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val())* 0.5).val(parseFloat($('#a4').val()).toFixed(2));
            $('#a3').val($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val());              
        }}
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<div>Lengde <input id="a1" type="text" value="0" /></div>
<div>Bredde <input id="a2" type="text" value="0" /></div>
<div>Kantklipp rundt plenen? <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox_check"></div>
<div>% <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox_check2"></div>
<div>Gjødsel (+2kr per kvm) <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox_check3"></div>
<div>Antall kvm <input id="a3" type="text" value="0" /></div>
<div>Pris <input id="a4" type="text" value="0" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use parseFloat() and wrap the addition in brackets. your values are text

Comment: Likes this?    `if ($('input.checkbox_check3').is(':checked')) {
    $('#a4').val(parseInt($('#a4').val() + 10));
   }`

Comment: $('#a4').val((parseFloat($('#a4').val()) )+ 10); }

Comment: Thank you! Got it working now. :)